# GraphQL error: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable

Tags: javascript, graphql, instanceof, graphql-js

I'm defining the following GraphQL type:

**interface.js**

```
import { 
    GraphQLInterfaceType,
    GraphQLNonNull, 
    GraphQLID 
} from 'graphql';


const NodeInterface = new GraphQLInterfaceType({
    name: 'Node',
    fields: {
        id: {
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)
        }
    }
});

export default NodeInterface;
```

**type.js**

```
 import { 
    GraphQLObjectType, 
    GraphQLInputObjectType,
    GraphQLNonNull,
    GraphQLID,
    GraphQLList,
    GraphQLString, 
    GraphQLInt, 
    GraphQLBoolean 
} from 'graphql';

 import NodeInterface from '../interfaces';

 import UserModel from '../../models/User';

 const fields = {
    id: {
        type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)
    },
    name: {
        type: GraphQLString
    },
    users: {
        type: new GraphQLList(UserType),
        resolve(company) {
            const { _id } = company;
            return UserModel.find({ companyId: _id }).exec();
        }
    }
 };

 export const CompanyType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Company',
    description: 'Company',
    interfaces: [NodeInterface],
    isTypeOf: value => value instanceof CompanyType, <<<< ERROR HERE
    fields: fields
 })
```

When running a  query on node I'm getting the following error:

```
query {
  node(id:"598360ab8713621aac426e88") {
    ... on Company {
            id
            name
        }
     }
  }
```

Result:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "node"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "node": null
  }
}
```

the problem is at `isTypeOf` of the `Company` type, but I don't know why it cannot evaluate the instanceof the created type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever GraphQL resolves a Type, it's passed some kind of business object to work with. It uses that business object to resolve the respective fields on the type. You can think of the `isTypeOf` method as a check to determine if the business object passed in should be resolved to this particular type.

In your app, when you make a query, you are getting data from your db and passing it to the type resolver. What your `isTypeOf` method needs to do is answer the question: does this data represent the type I'm trying to resolve?

If the ORM that you're using returns an instance of, for example, `CompanyModel`, then the `isTypeOf` method can simply be `value instanceof CompanyModel.`

If you're getting back an object that doesn't inherit from a descriptive prototype like that, you can implement whatever other check is necessary. For example, if your db row includes a `typename` field, you can check against that.

You can see a correct use of `isTypeOf` [here](https://github.com/mugli/learning-graphql/blob/master/7.%20Deep%20Dive%20into%20GraphQL%20Type%20System.md#graphqlinterfacetype).